# Помоги разобраться как работает "POST" запрос

Tags: javascript, ajax, веб-программирование, response

Всем привет. Изучаю AJAX.
Надо по клику на кнопку `"Add new user"` добавить пользователя в список `"User list"`. А потом, чтобы можно было нажать на пользователя и вывести доскональную информацию о нём. То есть мы отправляет `POST` запрос на сервер, а потом, если надо то выводим информацию о нём по клику. Суть следующая: когда я нажимаю по добавленному пользователю в списке, чтобы отобразилась информация о нём, то мне выдаёт в консоль ошибка 404, что означает проблема со стороны сервера. Я вот не пойму, получается, что наш пользователь висит в воздухе и мы можем работать с ним только локально, но не делая запросы `"GET"` к нему? C другими пользователя всё работает т.к они присутствуют по указанной ссылке, а наш получается нет.

```js
const userListEl = document.querySelector('.users-list');
const userInfoEl = document.querySelector('.user-info');
const apiURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

userListEl.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.dataset.userId) {
        getUsersHTML(onGetUserInfoHTML, e.target.dataset.userId);
        console.log(e.target.dataset.userId)
    };
})



// GET USER 
function getUsersHTML(cb, id) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

    xhr.open("GET", `${apiURL}/users${id ? '/' + id : ''}`)
    xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if (xhr.status !== 200) {
            console.log('ERROR', xhr.status);
            return;
        }
        cb(response);
    })
    xhr.send()

}

function onGetUserInfoHTML(user) {
    if (!user.id) {
        console.log("User not found");
        return;
    }

    renderUserInfo(user);
}

function onGetUsersCallback(users) {
    if (!users.length) {
        return;
    }
    renderUsersList(users);
}

function renderUsersList(users) {
    const fragment = users.reduce((acc, user) => {
        return acc + usersListItemTemplate(user);
    }, '')

    userListEl.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', fragment)
}

function renderUserInfo(user) {
    userInfoEl.innerHTML = "";

    const template = userInfoTemplate(user);
    userInfoEl.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", template)
}

function usersListItemTemplate(user) {
    return ` <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-user-id="${user.id}">
    ${user.name}
    </button>`
}

function userInfoTemplate(user) {
    return `
    <div class="card border-dark mb-3">
        <div class="card-header">${user.name}</div>
        <div class="card-body text-dark">
            <h5 class="card-title">${user.email}</h5>
            <ul class="list-group list-gruop-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item"><b>Nickname:</b> ${user.username}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"><b>Website:</b> ${user.website}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"><b>Company:</b> ${user.company.name}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"><b>City:</b> ${user.address.city}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-dark">Phone: ${user.phone}</div>
    </div>
    `
}


getUsersHTML(onGetUsersCallback)


// POST USER
const btn = document.querySelector('.add-user');


function createUser(body, cb) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", `${apiURL}/users`)
    xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        cb(response);
    })

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8')

    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(body))
}

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const newUser = {
        name: 'Anton',
        email: 'sdmk23@gmail.com',
        phone: '89232345452',
        website: 'xxx',
    }

    createUser(newUser, (user) => {
        const card = usersListItemTemplate(user)
        userListEl.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', card)

    })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <section class="users-wrapper mt-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            Users list
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group users-list">
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-6">
                    <div class="user-info"></div>
                </div>
            </div><button type="button" class="btn btn-success mt-1 add-user">Add new user</button>
        </div>
    
    </section>
    
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ошибка 404 означает что страница не существует, проверьте правильность url, куда идет обращение. Ошибки сервера это 5XX

Comment: Всё логично... те юзеры что вы с апи грузите есть, а тут захардкодить Антона решили, с чего ему быть на сервере?